# install application in iphone device through command line

Tags: command-line, xcodebuild

I'm using `xcodebuild install -alltargets -iphoneos4.2 -activeconfiguration provisioning_profile=path_of_my_provisioningprofile code_sign_identity=identity`.
This command is building my app and i am getting build file (.app) also.
But how to install the app in to device from command line.
Please help me in this issue.

Answer (score 20):

[`Fruitstrap`](https://github.com/ghughes/fruitstrap) is no longer maintained, for a more up to date project checkout the fork by PhoneGap called **[`ios-deploy`](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy)**.

To install run: `npm install -g ios-deploy`

Here are some examples of how to use it:

```
// deploy and debug your app to a connected device
ios-deploy --debug --bundle my.app

// deploy and launch your app to a connected device, but quit the debugger after
ios-deploy --justlaunch --debug --bundle my.app

// deploy and launch your app to a connected device, quit when app crashes or exits
ios-deploy --noninteractive --debug --bundle my.app

// Upload a file to your app's Documents folder
ios-deploy --bundle_id 'bundle.id' --upload test.txt --to Documents/test.txt
```

Comment: thanks! I got a working setup using iOS 9.3.1 and OS X 10.11.3

Comment: A modern, working answer in an often obsolete world. Cheers!

Comment: I don't believe it. It works. Out of the box. No setting required. AMAZING.

Comment: The install worked nicely but not the debugging: `error: python failed attempting to evaluate 'fruitstrap_device_app="/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/...`

Answer (score 6):

**Fruitstrap**:
https://github.com/ghughes/fruitstrap

Here's a good tutorial to set it up:
http://sgleadow.github.com/blog/2011/11/05/installing-ios-apps-on-the-device-from-the-command-line/

Answer (score 5):

Looking around found  https://github.com/benvium/libimobiledevice-macosx. This is a port from libimobiledevice to MAC-OS X. Its very useful and no jailbroken is needed. :P

Answer (score 4):

Use this beautiful script : http://gamua.com/blog/2012/03/how-to-deploy-ios-apps-to-the-iphone-via-the-command-line/
- Then connect iphone device via usb to mac running this command

To launch app on command line:

```
instruments -w 4xxxxxxxx9 -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate NITC -e UIASCRIPT Launch-App.js
```

format : `instruments -w <deviceid>  -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate <applicationname>  -e UIASCRIPT Launch-App.js`

My Launch-App.js has only one line - `var target = UIATarget.localTarget();`

This must be sufficient to launch application on device using command line

Comment: Whoa, I've never seen instruments mentioned when pushing an App or IPA to a device - +1. Is there a way to have instruments list the device ID's used with `-w`?

Comment: @noloader +1 for how to list devices IDs, I'd love to know.

Comment: Fruitstrap (what the link uses) is now abandoned and does not work with iOS 7 :(

Comment: In case anyone comes across this and is still wondering about the device IDs: `instruments -s devices`

Comment: This isn't working with Xcode 9.1—I don't appear to have `AutomationInstrument.bundle`.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

[how to intall an ipa/app file into iPhone with command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14652288/1040553)

Third solution with libimobiledevice.

Answer (score 1):

**ipatool**: https://github.com/majd/ipatool

Step 1: Search the app bundle id

```
 ./ipatool search testflight --limit 1

> ==> ℹ️    [Info] Searching for 'testflight' using the 'US' store front...
> ==> ℹ️    [Info] Found 1 result:
> 1. TestFlight: com.apple.TestFlight (3.1.0).
```

Step 2: Download the IPA

```
./ipatool download --bundle-identifier com.apple.TestFlight
```

Easy!

Answer (score 1):

Install following packages on MAC

```
brew install libimobiledevice  
brew install ideviceinstaller
```

After successfully installed above packages.

Use following command to install .ipa file on iOS devices:

```
ideviceinstaller -i <Path_to_your_ipa>
```

Thanks