# Push IPA to Device via Command Line (after xcodebuild)?

Tags: iphone, ipad, command-line, synchronization, xcodebuild

Is it possible to push an IPA to a device via the command line?

The IPA was built from the command line using `xcodebuild` and signed with a developer certificate. The device is not jail broken and was provisioned for development. In the case of a Bundle being delivered, I fix it up per [Ad-Hoc and App Store IPAs with xcrun](http://www.bdunagan.com/2011/12/12/ad-hoc-and-app-store-ipas-with-xcrun/).

I am aware of [fruitstrap](https://github.com/ghughes/fruitstrap). I don't want strip the App Bundle from the IPA ([fruitstrap](https://github.com/ghughes/fruitstrap) requirement), and I don't want the 'debug hook' provided by [fruitstrap](https://github.com/ghughes/fruitstrap).

The question is similar to [Install application in iphone device through command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481456/install-application-in-iphone-device-through-command-line), but I need Apple tools.

So far, I've only found manual methods using iTunes. (And as @fanneyward offered - mobile safari).

Comment: You need to use iTunes, or you can put ipa on your server and install from Safari mobile directly.

Comment: **ios-deploy --debug --bundle your_iPA_Path.app**.    This is the command to install ipa on device but make sure you have installed provisioning profile and certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Look at his answer:

[how to intall an ipa/app file into iPhone with command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14652288/1040553)

the 3rd solution with libimobiledevice.

Answer (score 1):

If you would consider using [Test Flight App](http://testflightapp.com) for distributing builds to devices (it's not clear from your question whether it's just for yourself or for beta testers), [Ray Wenderlich](http://raywenderlich.com) has [a great post on Automated Testing](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22816/beginning-automated-testing-with-xcode-part-22) that shows you how to automatically make [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) push builds to Test Flight. It's not exactly what you ask for, but definitely an okay alternative.