# Resign ios application before using libimobiledevice

Tags: ios

Do i have to resign my iOS application before using `ideviceinstaller`?
I have a `.ipa` file from a local build server, but I don't own the code.

Is it possible to install it on my iOS device using [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/)?

Comment: Can you install it using itunes ?

Comment: Yes I installed it , but i want to install it from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

If the **UDID** of your device was in a provisioning profile used to sign the app then you **will be able** to install it. Otherwise you have to sign the app with a provisioning profile that has the **UDID** of your device.

Here is how to check if your UDID is included:

Unpack the ipa file:

[image]

Browse package contents:

[image]

Look for .mobileprovisionfile

[image]

Open it in the text editor and verify if your UDID is in the list.

[image]

Comment: How can i check that?

Comment: I looked my file, and there is a tag : 
<key>ProvisonsAllDevices</key>
<true/>

the error i got from terminal:

Error : Could not locate iTunesMetadata.plist in archive ! Could not determine CFBundleName!

Answer (score 0):

As you said in a comment that you have isntalled so I assume the provisioing is not the issue here. Using `libimobiledevice` you do using commandline, have a look at a [similar and interconnected thread(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303741/push-ipa-to-device-via-command-line-after-xcodebuild).

Comment: When i try to install an app, I got the error: Error : Could not locate iTunesMetadata.plist in archive ! Could not determine CFBundleName!

I lood up for the solution for google, but none of them worked.