# xcodebuild install doesn't seem to work for iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration

I need to install my app to a device from a command line (for CI purposes). To that end i am using `xcodebuild install -scheme MyScheme -project Maps.xcodeproj CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Developer: me"  -destination 'platform=iOS,id=xxxxxxxx'`

When I run the command with the necessary keys (the scheme and the signing identity), the command completes successfully and reports "`** INSTALL SUCCEEDED **`", however, the app doesn't appear on the device.

I have seen the third party apps that claim to install your apps on devices, however, since they use private features, I am reluctant to use them.

Comment: Have u checked the following sof http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535392/how-to-intall-an-ipa-app-file-into-iphone-with-command-line/14652288#14652288

Comment: @casillas As I said, i don't want to use third party solutions. I am now looking at OS X server + Xcode Server. I will report when I succeed or fail.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I am encountering exact same issue.

Comment: The same question from 2023 - it writes "install succeeded", but actually no app on device - how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using xcodebuild test "parameters".
Your app will be installed and then you can run your instrumentation tests.

Comment: This does solve the issue of build not getting installed on the device.